# Match 2 Textboxes line order

Tags: c#, list, sorting, textbox, match

i'm looking for a way to order 2 different textboxes so that textbox 2 matches the same order that textbox 1 is in.

Textbox 2 will have the same strings with either ...Not Available or ....Available added to the end and in different order.

For example:

**Textbox 1**

```
orange
banana 
cranberry    
grape
apple
```

**Textbox 2**

```
banana....Available 
cranberry....Not Available 
apple....Available 
grape....Not Available     
orange....Available
```

The final output would make textbox 2 in the same order as textbox 1.

I don't want them sorted A-Z.

is there a way to sort a list based on the order it is in textbox1 ?

```
List<string> listtomatchtextbox1= new List<string>();

            foreach (var line in textbox1.Lines)
            {
                listtomatchtextbox1.Add(line);
            }

listtomatchtextbox1.Sort(sortbytextbox1); //???

foreach (string s in listtomatchtextbox1)
                {
                    textbox2.AppendText(s);
                    textbox2.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
                }
```

any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Both textboxes contain the same strings and you want the same order? Are you sure that you don't want to set `TextBox2.Text=TextBox1.Text`?

Comment: Thanks Tim, i edited my original question, i forgot that textbox 2 will have a slightly different string added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole code would be

```
List<string> tb1lines = textbox1.Lines.ToList();
List<string> tb2lines = textbox2.Lines.ToList();
List<string> newtb2lines = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in tb1lines)
    newtb2lines.Add(tb2lines.Where(l => l.StartsWith(s)).ToList()[0]);

textbox2.Lines = newtb2lines.ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry i fixed my original question, I forgot textbox 2 would have an addition string added on the end of it.

Comment: OK i'll try that , would i put that in my 2nd foreach loop ?

Comment: I hope this is what you've been looking for